Injecting multiple implementations for the same provider in Angular
The problem
I have the following setup in my Angular template:
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab *ngIf="sees1">
    <app-custom-table
      (columnButtonClick)="service1.columnClicked($event)">
    </app-custom-table>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab *ngIf="sees2">
    <app-custom-table>
    </app-custom-table>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab *ngIf="sees3">
    <app-custom-table>
    </app-custom-table>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab *ngIf="sees4">
    <app-custom-table>
    </app-custom-table>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab *ngIf="sees5">
    <app-custom-table
      (columnButtonClick)="service5.columnClicked($event)">
    </app-custom-table>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>

I want each of the app-custom-table's to be injected with a different service implementation in order to be able to show and process different data.
The idea
I'm actually trying to change my existing solution which included passing the service as an @Input() argument directly to each of the components. Like so:
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab *ngIf="sees1">
    <app-custom-table [service]="serviceImpl1"
      (columnButtonClick)="service1.columnClicked($event)">
    </app-custom-table>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab *ngIf="sees2">
    <app-custom-table [service]="serviceImpl2">
    </app-custom-table>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab *ngIf="sees3">
    <app-custom-table [service]="serviceImpl3">
    </app-custom-table>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab *ngIf="sees4">
    <app-custom-table [service]="serviceImpl4">
    </app-custom-table>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab *ngIf="sees5">
    <app-custom-table [service]="serviceImpl5"
      (columnButtonClick)="service5.columnClicked($event)">
    </app-custom-table>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>

I'm trying to move away from this approach because it seems like a bad approach.
I want something like this:
@Component({
  providers: [
    { provide: BaseService, useClass: ImplementationService1 },
    { provide: BaseService, useClass: ImplementationService2 },
    { provide: BaseService, useClass: ImplementationService3 },
    { provide: BaseService, useClass: ImplementationService4 },
    { provide: BaseService, useClass: ImplementationService5 }]
})

but Angular obviously can't know where to inject each of the corresponding services.
Maybe it's important to note that all of the implementations extend the BaseService class which is an abstract class with default implementation of the methods which mostly don't change, at least for most implementations.
The question
Is there a way to let Angular know which service to inject or should I stick to the current approach (injecting service as an Input() argument)? Is the current approach even that bad?
EDIT:
CustomTable<T> and BaseService<T> are both generic classes, additionally BaseService<T> is abstract class without @Injectable decorator. All the ImplementationServices extend the BaseService with a concrete model as T.

According to the discussions in the answers: It would be helpful to know, why do your services need to be different classes? Can't it be the same service class with different settings per instance? This would make everything much easier.

@JSONDerulo well, not really. Some of them could be how you suggested. But some of them need additional data processing and overriding some of the default implementations. That's why the architecture is created in a way that each of the models has it's own Service.

Everyone is trying to answer your question, but nobody is telling you the truth : inputs are the way to go. I don't get why you think it's a bad approach, but it is EXACTLY why the inputs exist !

@MGX While I do agree that Input() is a pretty simple way to overcome this, in some cases you may want the Service to be available in the constructor of the Component. Otherwise you just have to wait until ngOnInit() call and do the undefined checks in the template before that call.

@Sulejman if your only issue is about undefined checks, consider using inputs instead of the accepted solution, just compare the complexity of both solutions ...

@MGX Well as I already stated in the post, I actually am using inputs right now. But yes I will consider not moving to this new approach since it seems like unnecessary wrapper/boilerplate magic. Thank you for the input tho, I really thought I've done it bad to start with.

I tried to abstract a solution as mush as possible, however there's a limit to how abstract things can end up.
At some point, since you're using the same common table but with different services, you have to identify which service to be used at which point.
With the below solution, which can be found in this working stackblitz, the configuration have been moved to an Injection Token, and custom components thus leveraging DI to carry your work.
The idea behind the solution is to

Reduce pollution from the main host component. Injecting 6 services to be passed as input to the generic table component can end up with ugly and unmaintainable code
Your reusable table can leverages DI to resolve the service instance it needs to use.
Your reusable table no longer have unnecessary input fields that are not related to the generic functionality of the table
The introduction of the wrapper components handle configuration of DI to be used by its children. Additionally, the name of the component already hints to what data

BaseService abstract, as per your requirement, cannot be injected
export abstract class BaseService {

  abstract getData():string;
}

Service 1 and Service 2, extending / implementing abstract service
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class OneService extends BaseService {
  override getData(): string {
    return 'One Service';
  }
}

@Injectable({providedIn:'root'})
export class TwoService extends BaseService {
  override getData(): string {
    return 'Two Service';
  }
}

Injection Token + Factory Function
export let ServiceToken :InjectionToken<BaseService> = new InjectionToken('service-injection');

export let injectionFactory = (key:string) => {
  switch(key) {
    case "1":
      return inject(OneService);
    case "2":
      return inject(TwoService);
     default:
      throw new Error('not-supported');
  }
};

CustomTable, reusable, as per your requirement
@Component({
 standalone:true,
 selector:'my-table',
 template:`
    <div>My Table {{key}}</div>
 `,
})
export class TableComponent {

    constructor(@Inject(ServiceToken) public serivce:BaseService){};

    get key():string {
      return this.serivce.getData();
    }
}

Wrapper components for the table, that injects your specific service to be used by the reusable table
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'one-table',
  imports: [TableComponent],
  providers: [{ provide: ServiceToken, useExisting: OneService }],
  template: `
   <my-table>
 `,
})
export class OneTableComponent {}

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'two-table',
  imports: [TableComponent],
  providers: [{ provide: ServiceToken, useExisting: TwoService }],,
  template: `
    <my-table>
 `,
})
export class TwoTableComponent {}


This is probably the closest to the solution that it gets as already mentioned. Also, I created another version without ServiceToken and injectionFactory which also works. Can you provide a reason why you added that instead of just doing it like in my fork?

I read from some of the comments / discussion that you are unable to inject the Abstract service, and you were getting an erro, so I opted for a different solution. However, if injecting the Abstract Service works for your real solution, that's better. Code becomes much simpler

I mean, you can't inject an abstract Service directly (like this: providers: [BaseService]) but you can provide an implementation (OneService or TwoService) for the abstract Service through the providers array (like this providers: [{provide: BaseService, useClass: OneService}]). In this case the abstract BaseService defined in the constructor of TableComponent is just populated with OneService or TwoService respectively since they both extend BaseService

Why don't you add the service to the providers of the app-custom-table component, so the service will be created for each component instance? Instead of passing services via inputs, you can just inject and use the service directly in the child component, and it will be a separate service instance for each component.
@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-table',
  // this will create a new instance of the service per component instance
  providers: [{ provide: BaseService, useClass: ImplementationService }],
})
export class CustomTableComponent {
  constructor(private service: BaseService) {}

  columnButtonClick(event: unknown) {
    this.service.columnClicked(event);
  }
}

See the dependency injection guide.
If you want to call the service not every time but based on a condition, you can add an input to the component to control this.

The same problem as in the other answer.

@Sulejman this is important information which should be part of the question. However in this case it doesn't really matter, just create one service and add it to the component providers. Will update my answer.

UPDATE:
In the parent service use different instances instead of BaseService.
@Component({
  providers: [
    ImplementationService1,
    ImplementationService2,
    ImplementationService3,
    ImplementationService4,
    ImplementationService5,
})
export class SomeComponent {

    constructor(
      private impSer1: ImplementationService1
      private impSer2: ImplementationService2
      private impSer3: ImplementationService3
      private impSer4: ImplementationService4
      private impSer5: ImplementationService5
    ) {}

The add these to the HTML.
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab *ngIf="sees1">
    <app-custom-table [service]="impSer1"
      (columnButtonClick)="service1.columnClicked($event)">
    </app-custom-table>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab *ngIf="sees2">
    <app-custom-table [service]="impSer2">
    </app-custom-table>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab *ngIf="sees3">
    <app-custom-table [service]="impSer3">
    </app-custom-table>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab *ngIf="sees4">
    <app-custom-table [service]="impSer4">
    </app-custom-table>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab *ngIf="sees5">
    <app-custom-table [service]="impSer5"
      (columnButtonClick)="service5.columnClicked($event)">
    </app-custom-table>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>


Firstly There must a simpler way to solve what you want.
But for now, this is my suggestion.
Add the service to the providers array of the component app-custom-table.
@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-table',
  ...
  providers: [{ provide: BaseService, useClass: ImplementationService },],
})
export class CustomTable {

Now all the child components have a unique instance.
Then take a view child from the parent to the child components to get the current instance, you can use a getter for this.
...
@ViewChild(CustomTable) customTable: CustomTable;

get baseServiceInstance() {
    return this.customTable?.baseService;
}

Note: the service will be available only on ngAfterViewInit, so start using this logic from there and not on ngOnInit or constructor.

The suggested solution doesn't work since I stated that the BaseService is an abstract class. So putting it in the providers array results in: Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.

@Sulejman updated my answer, you only need one service, the instances are created automatically when you add them in the providers array

Okay, I edited the question a bit since you might have missed it. Notice how all the implementations are actually different services. I can't do what you suggest because each of the ImplementationServices is different. And there isn't a single (let's say) ImplementationService1 that all of the other ones can inherit from to create this ImplementationService, which you suggest I should use as a BaseService implementation.

@Sulejman Then why dont you provide them as is, without the base service, here you are providing a single service BaseService with multiple implementations, which does not make sense

Think about BaseService as an interface service which I use in the CustomTable constructor. I don't quite understand how you suggest me to "provide them as is" (maybe you can put another answer for that) because in the conustructor of Custom table i have it defined like this:
constructor(private service: BaseService) {}

@Sulejman updated my answer, I dont think you need BaseService, if you want extend the services to use BaseService like export class ImplementationService1 extends BaseService {. But when using in providers use them directly. You should use the service directly from @Input not from private service: BaseService

Okay so my original/existing solution (so the one with Input) is a valid way to inject a service? I mean I wanted to change this because it seemed to me that services should be always be available in the constructor. Thanks anyways for your input.

@Sulejman You can do this, but it involves extra overhead of adding a wrapper component which changes the provider, it just looks ugly, please explain you original problem clearly, maybe there is a simpler way without so many service instances.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
